# How to make Policy Auto-Discovery new Laravel feature work with my models in a different folder?

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have just updated my Laravel to 5.8 and can't make my Policies auto-discovery work.

I think it's because all my models are in *app/Models*. 
The documentation says that I can change the default behavior using this gate.

```
Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing(function ($modelClass) {
    // return policy class name...
});
```

But I can't make it work. The check function '''$user->can()''' always return false for all my Policies and models.
Is it really the problem? The models folder, or I'm missing somenting?

By the way, everything works great if I map it manually in the **$policies** array at **AuthServiceProvider.php**

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If anyone has this problem, here is how I corrected it.

It turned out that the `App/Models` structure was the problem. The *magic* done by laravel to guess the policy name considers the location of the model.

To bypass this behavior put the code below inside `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php` in the boot function.

```
Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing(function ($modelClass) {
    return 'App\\Policies\\' . class_basename($modelClass) . 'Policy';
});
```

It will force to look at `App/Policies` instead of `App/Models/Policies`. (change accordingly)

And then I realized that the Policies folder should be allocated inside `App/Models` 'cause it is where the model live in, but hey, who knows? I guess that putting my models in a different folder will make my life harder.

Bye, hope to help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone has changed App folder name, as I did, you can use the following code:

```
    Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing(function ($modelClass) {
        $classDirnameArray = explode('\\', str_replace('/', '\\', dirname(str_replace('\\', '/', $modelClass))));
        if ($classDirnameArray[0] === app()::APP_FOLDER) {
            $classDirnameArray =  array_slice($classDirnameArray, 1);
        }
        return app()::APP_FOLDER.'\\Policies\\'. implode("\\",$classDirnameArray) . "\\" . class_basename ( $modelClass).'Policy';
    });
```

Bear in mind you probably have changed the App name path in the Application.php file, so what I did was to create a constant variable `APP_FOLDER` that contains the string of the app folder name and I can just call it wherever I am using `app()::APP_FOLDER`.

I.E. if you have a model `MyApp\Models\Core\User` the guess policy name would be `MyApp\Policies\Models\Core\User`.

Any concerns don't hesitate to ask me about it, and I hope this could help too.

PS: I used `PHP v7.2.9` and `Laravel v5.8.37`